# Getting rid of the standard items in an UIMenuController

Tags: objective-c, ios, first-responder, uimenucontroller

I'm working on a very small editor in iOS. It only has one view, one button and a textView. When the button gets pressed, a custom UIMenuController pops up with 3 options: toggle bold, toggle italics and toggle cursive.

This is working very well, however, if I press the button when the UITextView is the first responder, it also shows the two default menu items, named 'select' and 'select all'.

I want to get rid of them but I'm not sure how to do this. This is the code that gets called when the button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)settingsPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIMenuController *sharedController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];

    UIMenuItem *menuItem1 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:bold ? @"Bold off" : @"Bold on" action:@selector(toggleBold:)];
    UIMenuItem *menuItem2 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:italics ? @"Italics off" : @"Italics on" action:@selector(toggleCursive:)];
    UIMenuItem *menuItem3 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:underline ? @"Underline off" : @"Underline on" action:@selector(toggleUnderline:)];

    NSArray *menuItems = @[menuItem1, menuItem2, menuItem3];

    CGRect drawRect = [sender convertRect:[sender bounds] toView:self.view];
    [sharedController setTargetRect:drawRect inView:self.view];

    [sharedController setMenuItems:menuItems];
    [sharedController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];

    [sharedController setMenuItems:nil];
}
```

Can anyone explain me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a subclass of `UITextView`.  In your subclass, override `canPerformAction:withSender:` to return `NO` if the action is `@selector(select:)` or `@selector(selectAll:)`.  For more information:

- [*Managing the Selection and Edit Menu*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/AddingCustomEditMenuItems/AddingCustomEditMenuItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH13-SW3)
- [*UIMenuController Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIMenuController)
- [`-[UIResponder canPerformAction:withSender:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006783-CH4-SW17)
- [*UIResponderStandardEditActions Protocol Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/UIResponderStandardEditActions.html#//apple_ref/occ/cat/UIResponderStandardEditActions)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer, I will try to implement this :)

Comment: Is this possible without subclassing? I am facing this issue with UIWebView but have limited options to overwrite implementation used by the fmk...